# Radio button is not reading value in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am simply trying to read the value from a `radio button` but it returns undefined.

I am not using jquery. I think the code is fine but in chrome and explorer it doesnt do anything and when I print out the length of the variable "opi" it gives `undefined`.

**Code**:

```js
function calc() {
  var v1 = document.getElementById("Text1").value;

  var v2 = document.getElementById("Text2").value;


  var opi = document.getElementsByName("op");

  for (var i = 0; i < opi.length; i++) {

    if (opi[i].checked == true) {
      var operator = opi[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (operator == "+") {
    var v3 = parseInt(v1) + parseInt(v2);
  }
  if (operator == "-") {
    var v3 = parseInt(v1) - parseInt(v2);
  }

  if (operator == "*") {
    var v3 = parseInt(v1) * parseInt(v2);
  }

  if (operator == "/") {
    var v3 = parseInt(v1) / parseInt(v2);
  }

  document.write(v3);

}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>   My calculator </h2>
  <p>First Value:
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>Second value:
    <input id="Text2" type="text" />
    <br />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" value="+" name="op" />"+"</p>
  <p>
    <input id="Radio2" type="radio" value="-" name="op" />"-"</p>
  <p>
    <input id="Radio3" type="radio" value="*" name="op" />"*"</p>
  <p>
    <input id="Radio4" type="radio" name="op" value="/" />"/"</p>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calc()" />

</body>
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f8j4L5tu/. Are you sure `JScript1.js` is being loaded?

Comment: Hi, I just tried your code on code snippet and it seems to work.

Comment: Works fine for me. Checkout this plunker.  http://plnkr.co/edit/PuWeSNRrT9xuB5pWTEOS?p=preview

Your pasted HTML is missing an opening `<html>` tag, but I doubt that is the cause.

Comment: Did you put the function call in a document.onload listener?

Comment: Just an FYI - rather than looping through all of the radios to get the checked one, you can just do this - `var opi = document.querySelector('input[name = "op"]:checked').value;`

Comment: it started working for me too the next day, didnt make any changes